# Apply value to a value from foreach loop PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a solution to apply a discount to a value based on an foreach loop of items, my main problem is that if the second item meet the requirements it will apply on it too, so what i want is just to apply to the first of the item that has found with the requirement and then pass to other action.

```
    echo '<pre>';

        $requeriment = 299;
        $items = array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 1,
                            'price' => 199,
                            'quantity' => 1
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id' => 2,
                            'price' => 399,
                            'quantity' => 1
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id' => 3,
                            'price' => 199,
                            'quantity' => 1
                        )
        );

        $flag = false;

        foreach($items as $item){
            $totalItem = $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
            if($totalItem > $requeriment){
                if(!$flag){
                    $flag = true;
                    echo 'Disc 1% - ' . $item['id'];
                    echo "<br>";
                }else if($flag){
                    echo 'Disc 2% - ' . $item['id'];
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                continue;
            }
            echo 'Disc 2% - ' . $item['id'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    //Ok, it found ID 2 with a value bigger than requirement and the job is done.

//Now if trough loop it not found item that meet the requirement 
//it need now to sum values to get the required value to meet the requirement
//and apply a 1% the the 2 items that made that sum, then apply 2% to the rest of ids.
```

Is there a way to to this in the same loop?

Comment: continue; http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Add buffer variable and change it only in 1% discount case

Comment: You can use flag. If flag is false enter to if and apply 1% discount. Then set flag to true.

Comment: All right, continue will skip over the id 2 and 3 and will give me the id 1 at the end. if i apply to id 2 a discount of 1% how i will skip the id 3? applying a flag to what id?

Comment: I have applied your ideas guys, and it seem to be fine, but i still have a problem, if none of the ids meet the requirement, it need now to sum the ids until get the sum required.

Comment: Sorry guys for the miss understanding i have edited the question, and i think the best way to resolve it i need to post an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
  $i=0;
  foreach $items as $item{
   $i++;
  $totalItem = $item->price * $item->quantity;
if($totalItem > $requeriment){

//Apply a discount of 1%
    if($i==1){

     // for discount 1
    }elseif($i==2){
          // for discount 2
       }
  }
```

As same as another discount.